# Angular Karma test not running properly, gives error "Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to add unit tests to an angular controller using karma but I've run into an issue and I need some help. I've found similar questions asked here but none have led me to an answer. I've tried changing the order of the "files" array in the karma.conf.js thinking perhaps they weren't being loaded properly but that hasn't yielded any results. When I run 'karma start karma.conf.js' I get the error

**console error from karma**

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module undefined due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined
at assetArg (D:/xxxx/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1580
...
...
...  (long callstack within angular.js and angular-mocks.js)
...
...
at workFn (D:/xxxx/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2172
```

I'm only using one test file for now, and it's very basic. The module name is correct and the 'myApp.views.view1` file is being served by the karma server, the "debug" level karma logging confirms it

**view1_test.js**

```
'use strict';

describe('myApp.views.view1 module', function() {

  beforeEach(module('myApp.views.view1',[]));

  describe('view1 controller', function(){

    it('should exist....', inject(function($controller) {
      //spec body
      var view1Ctrl = $controller('View1Ctrl');
      expect(view1Ctrl).toBeDefined();
    }));

  });
});
```

And heres' the view controller it's testing

**view1.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.views.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'src/views/view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope','$anchorScroll',function($scope,$anchorScroll) {
    //scroll to top of page
    $anchorScroll();

    $scope.testVar = "it works, congrats!";


}]);
```

**directory structure**

```
/
.bowerrc
.gitignore
bower.json
package.json
karma.conf.js
/sass_styles
    base.scss
/app
    index.html
    /src
         app.js
         /bower_components
         /directives
             /example
                 directive.js
                 template.html
         /views
             /view1
                 view1.html
                 view1.js
                 view1_test.js
         /styles
             base.css
```

This is my karma.conf.js file. I'm using PhantomJS as the browser and html2js preprocessor to include directive .html templates that use 'templateURL'

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({

        basePath : './app/',

        preprocessors: {
            'src/directives/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
        },

        files : [
            'src/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'src/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
            'src/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'src/directives/**/*.js',
            'src/views/**/*.js',
            //directive templates
            'app/src/directives/**/**.html'
        ],

        autoWatch : true,

        // level of logging
        // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        browsers : ['PhantomJS'],

        plugins : [
                'karma-chrome-launcher',
                'karma-firefox-launcher',
                'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
                'karma-jasmine',
                'karma-junit-reporter',
                'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor'
            ],

        junitReporter : {
          outputFile: '../test_out/unit.xml',
          suite: 'unit'
        },

        ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
            // strip app from the file path
            stripPrefix: 'app/',
            stripSufix: '.ext',
            // prepend this to the 
            prependPrefix: 'served/',

            // setting this option will create only a single module that contains templates 
            // from all the files, so you can load them all with module('foo') 
            moduleName: 'templates'
        }


  });
};
```

Apologies for copy pasting a ton of stuff but this is an involved process and I want to make sure I'm not missing one small part. So what am I doing wrong here that's causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you get the module in your spec file test setup, you are actually creating it by specifying the second argument, so it just clean up everything that is registered under that module.

Change:

```
 beforeEach(module('myApp.views.view1',[]));
```

to

```
 beforeEach(module('myApp.views.view1'));
```

and also when you instantiate the controller using `$controller` you need to supply the scope, because you are injecting `$scope` in your controller and there is no `$scopeProvider` that exists it is a special dependency injected, so you need to provide it.

Something like this:

```
it('should exist....', inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
  //spec body
  var scope = $rootScope.$new();
  var view1Ctrl = $controller('View1Ctrl', {$scope:scope});
  expect(view1Ctrl).toBeDefined();
}));
```

Comment: good catch. but now I'm faced with a new error (of course)

"Error:[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvier <- $scope <- View1Ctrl".  Do i need to manually specify an injection of the $scopeProvider somewhere?

Comment: You need to supply the scope in the locals. il update my answer

Comment: perfect, thanks for the help. I wrestled with this for awhile